# Ant SQL Transaction target, commit after x amount of statements?

Tags: sql, ant, commit, autocommit

Ant SQL Transaction target seems to have options to commit after done, or auto-commit after each statement. The target seems to not take in a property that would commit after x statements have been read. Does the Ant target behave correctly if I manually generate "commit" statements after e.g. 1000 statements have been read, or what will happen when the Ant target reaches its end; will it try to re-commit the whole file again even though portions have already been committed?

Comment: assuming when autocommit is off ant executes `start transaction` at the begining of transaction target and `commit` ant the end, i think you can insert `commit; start transaction;` pairs to avoid nested transactions.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying this, apparently once can place COMMIT statements between INSERT statements using the Ant target and a new unit of work is created. Therefore Ant will at the end only commit the new unit of work and not commit all statements.